# Trying to make a Zxing winforms sample decode more formats including code_39

Tags: c#, winforms, zxing, zxing.net

I'm trying to work with winforms c# samples, as eventually this is going in an existing winforms app.

I found a nice small example for taking input from a video camera and getting a barcode and then decoding it. Works great...

but it doesn't decode the type of barcode we are printing in-house, (i think it's code 39, but i'm not sure so i need a more general answer if possible.)

Here is the code i'm using, as my sample winform, there are several controls used but not declared here.

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using ZXing;

namespace zxingTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        FilterInfoCollection filterInfoCollection;
        VideoCaptureDevice videoCaptureDevice;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        videoCaptureDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice( filterInfoCollection[cboCamera.SelectedIndex].MonikerString );
        videoCaptureDevice.NewFrame += FinalFrame_NewFrame;
        videoCaptureDevice.Start();
    }

    private void Form1_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        filterInfoCollection = new FilterInfoCollection( FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice );
        foreach ( FilterInfo Device in filterInfoCollection )
            cboCamera.Items.Add( Device.Name );
        cboCamera.SelectedIndex = 0;
        videoCaptureDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice();
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void FinalFrame_NewFrame( object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs )
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = ( Bitmap ) eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        BarcodeReader Reader = new BarcodeReader();
        //BarDecoder

        if (null != pictureBox1.Image)
        {
            Result result = Reader.Decode((Bitmap) pictureBox1.Image);
            if (result != null)
            {
                txtResult.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            //Result result = Reader.((Bitmap) pictureBox1.Image);
            //if ()
        }
    }

    private void btnDecode_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        //timer1.Start();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing( object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e )
    {
        if ( videoCaptureDevice.IsRunning == true )
            videoCaptureDevice.Stop();
    }
}
```

}

In the timer1_tick method, it decodes a UPC barcode just fine... but ours are ignored.

There are lots of examples for android, etc, but I can't find any for straight windows and  I haven't found decoratively that its identical across implementations.

How do i convert the sample above to process more types, specifically code_93

I found info about using BarDecoder instead of BarReader, but it does not seem to be a declared type

Here is the barcode I'm trying to read

[image]

Comment: I tried the current winforms demo application from the zxing.net project (https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/tree/master/Clients/WindowsFormsDemo) with your sample image and it decodes successfully. It is a Code 39. Your code in the method timer1_Tick is ok. If no barcode format is specified zxing tries all supported formats.

Comment: Turns out the camera i have it too low a resolution to see the barcode with sufficient clarity